# QtConcurrent::run() causes QWaitCondition destroyed messages

Tags: windows, multithreading, qt

I’m trying to run a function of a class using the QtConcurrent::run() method. The thread runs and does exactly what it should. However, when the thread ends, I get this error message in the console:

```
QWaitCondition: Destroyed while threads are still waiting
```

It works fine on Linux without any error message, but application crashes in Windows when i close the application

Here is the code of main function:

```
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QtSingleApplication a(argc, argv);

        if(a.isRunning()&&argc==2)
        {
            a.sendMessage(argv[1]);
            return 0;
        }

        else if (a.isRunning())
        {
              return 0;
        }

        testApp w;

        testApp.show();

        a.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);
        if(argc==2)
        {
            w.showDialog(argv[1]);
        }

        QObject::connect(&a, SIGNAL(messageReceived(const QString&)),
                         &w, SLOT(showDialog(QString)));



        return a.exec();
    }
```

**Edit:**

```
void MyClass::ready()
{
 QtConcurrent::run (this,&MyClass::start);
}

void MyClass::start()
{

  // do something
}
```

Comment: Can you show minimal example for this to reproduce? `main()` function is hardly telling anything.